# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1 + \gamma(n)}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find out for what $\gamma(n)$ series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1 + \gamma(n)}}
$$
converges.

It is well-known that for $\gamma(n) = const > 0$ it converges and for $\gamma(n) = const \leq 0$ it does not. Also I know that if $n^{\gamma(n)} = \log^{1+\varepsilon}(n) \Rightarrow \gamma(n) = \frac{(1+\varepsilon)\log(\log(n))}{\log(n)}$ it converges. But are there any better results?

Comment: This might be useful: [Borderline between divergence and convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#Borderline_between_divergence_and_convergence).

Answer (score 0):

Every series $\sum a_n$ with positive terms ($a_n > 0$) can be represented in this way by setting:
$$\gamma(n) = \begin{cases}
-1 & a_n = 1, \\
-1 - \frac{\ln n}{\ln a_n} & a_n \neq 1.
\end{cases}$$
So essentially you're asking "when does a series with positive terms converge?". There is no satisfying answer to that: you can apply tests, give necessary conditions, sufficient conditions... But there is no general, usable criterion (besides the trivial "the series converges") that would work.